# Trouble with linebreaks in Django templates using a SQL database

Tags: python, html, django, filter, server

Okay so I had a project that was passed to me.  My school adviser is interested in adding bullet lists with line breaks to the output text display for a online quiz.  The quiz is powered via django and sqlite3. I am very new to django and db handling.  right now I have this as my html template code:

```
<head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <h2> blank 
         Survey Question {{q.snum}} </h2>
<!-- It appears that {{q.snum}} isn't being used-->

<div class="question">

    <span id = qspan>
    {{surv.text}}
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id = m_info>
    {{surv.more_info|linebreaks}}
    </span>

</div> 



<div id="ready_set_go" class "gq">

</div>

<div id="Back_Button" class "Back">

</div>

<div id="debug" data-gameid="{{g.id}}"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The linebreak filter in the m_info works per say. However, the output is this:

```
 <p> 
    "<pre>{{Examples: Consumables, energy, ect..'\*well''\• Hello People'\ • I miss you' }}</pre>"
    </p>
```

I have tried a multitude of ways manipulating the text in the db table, but it seems to throw it in quotes and not linebreak at all.  Lastly, it should be noted that I wrote a dummy string to test the linebreaks functionalalty but that also did not work.  example  {{'hello \n world'|linebreaks}}

I apologize if this is coming off very noobish.

Comment: Can you inspect your HTML and give us what `{{'hello \n world'|linebreaks}}` turns into?

Comment: <p>hello \n world</p>